# How do I enable double-tap (right click) drag on touchpad?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I remember there being an option I had to tick to enable it but can't find it anymore since reinstalling my OS. I've looked in gnome/unity tweaks and settings. I must be missing it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally just found the solution:

Just the same as left click draggng - double tap, but the first tap is with two fingers and the second with one and then drag.

This works on Gnome 44.1 under Wayland with libinput. I don't know if it would work on X, but it should.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I frequently use the "Resize with with Secondary-Click" (Window Action key under Gnome Tweaks) with a mouse but couldn't figure out to do it with a trackpad.  This is great!

Confirmed it works on X (Gnome 3.32)

Comment: ...Also this allows you to do "locked" right click drags if you have locked drags enabled for regular tap.

Answer (score 1):

You can tune this with the gnome tweak tool `gnome-tweaks` or with this simple gsettings command :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad 'fingers'
```

You can also install the `gnome-tweaks` tool

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not quite what I meant. If you are using a touchpad with no buttons, to left click drag you double tap and drag. For right click drag you double tap with two fingers and drag. But for me,  double tapping with two fingers immediately brings up the menu and disables mouse movement until I let go.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? Unity uses right-click drag for movement